# JavaScript (Angular) array not returning?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

so i am working on emptying a property (polygon) from an array of objects [image]

```js
 deleteAllZones = () => {
        let assetVal = this.asset.$$state.value
        let mapId = this.siMapUtils.mapId;
        console.log('load',assetVal)
        var polygons = assetVal.forEach(function (a) {
                console.log('a.poly',a.polygon)
                return a.polygon
            
        })
        console.log('test',polygons);
        let message = this.$filter('translate')('SI-MESSAGES.DELZONE-MSG');
        let title = this.$filter('translate')('SUBHEADER.DELZONE-TITLE');
        let button = this.$filter('translate')('BUTTON.DELETE');
        this.siAlertDialog.confirm(message, title, button)
        .then(()=>{
            this.siGeography.removePolygonFromMap('showAllAreas', mapId).then(()=>{
            this.toastIt.simple(this.$filter('translate')('SI-MESSAGES.ZONE-DELETED'))

            })
        })
    }
```

in **var polygons** i was able to iterate and console just the polygon property of all the object in the array (a.polygon) . But its returning undefined (return a.polygon) when i console 'polygons', but console.log('a.poly',a.polygon) is showing the array in the console[image]

```
 var polygons = assetVal.forEach(function (a) {
            console.log('a.poly',a.polygon)
            return a.polygon

    })
```

eventually i want to say polygons = null when this function execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `Array#Map`. This will construct an array with each returned value from the callback function.

Modify this block of code to read:

```
var polygons = assetVal.map(function (a) {
    console.log('a.poly',a.polygon)
    return a.polygon       
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control

Comment: i see that works, so as i described above i am creating this is function to delete the polygons. if i have a service like this 'this.siAsset.updateComponent( _polygons)' to delete the polygons, would i be able to say  let _polygons = assetVal.map(function (a) {
            return a.polygon = [] //empty array
        }) and pass _polygons as a parameter in that service?

Comment: @AnuRajan that will create an array of empty arrays. If you'd like to maintain the structure of each `a` object, but empty out `a.polygon`, then you should do: `a.polygon = []; return a;` inside the `map` function. First we're modifying the `polygon` property of `a`, then we're returning that modified `a`